# getting value from a tuple of tuple

Tags: python

I am new to python, I need help with how can I get the returning values from a function call.
I tried doing this which is apparently wrong I need to assign the returning values to the mentioned variables and I cant make changes on how I return the values from the function as that is what is needed in the question.

```
((cross_low,cross_high),cross_sum)=find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high)
```

I am returning this type of value from the `find_maximum_crossing_subarray` function:

```
tup=(max_left,max_right)
tup1=(tup,left_sum+right_sum)
return tup1
```

Comment: What is the value of left_sum and right_sum? When I write some test code where max_left, max_right, left_sum, and right_sum are floats, I get no error and it all works fine. What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error?

Comment: can you provides some sample data, some inputs and outputs you would expect. Especially the format of the output ?

Comment: please wrap your code in a [mcve]. probably a typo somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the outside enclosing parenthesis:

```
(cross_low, cross_high), cross_sum = find_maximum_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high)
```

Comment: Dropping those parentheses makes no difference in my own test code.

Comment: it's not the issue at all. those parens aren't needed but also not a problem

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange syntax, but basically you're being shown the return signature from `find_maximum_crossing_subarray(..)`.

You can see a simplified version,

```
def some_function():
    return (1, 2), 3

x = ((a, b), c) = some_function()

print(x, a, b, c)

...
... output:
((1, 2), 3) 1 2 3
```

Notice how I still had access to `a`, `b`, and `c`. Similarly, you will have access to your `cross_*` variables.

If you need to find the max of something, [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) is a built-in function, and so is [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

---

If you can change the return signature of `find_maximum_crossing_subarray(..)` I would do this instead:

```
    # ..
    return max_left, max_right, left_sum + right_sum


results = find_maximum(A, low, mid, high)

cross_low, cross_high, cross_sum = results
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer their question. Granted, there isn't enough information given currently to actually answer their question.

Comment: Well, what is the question? He needs access to `cross_low`, `cross_high` and `cross_sum`...the first example shows that he has access all along. He also implies he can't change the return signature, which is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: What is the question is a good question. Like I said, he hasn't given us enough information. All we know is "this which is apparently wrong", but the code as it is looks like it should run. We don't have enough information to debug why this code isn't working.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AbdulSamad921/0c894f7dac3c61435401fd3b4bae9155
Here is my sample code